# Using Google Script I want to add a timestamp to each row of the result

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to add a timestamp to each row of the result. I have attempted to add a separate timestamp script on edit but that is not working. Below is the code I am using.

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {

 var threads = GmailApp.search("Gmail Search"); 
 var message = threads[0].getMessages();
 var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[1];


 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID'); 
 var tab = sheet.getSheetByName('Data');

 var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

 var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();

 var dataRange = tab.getRange(startRow,1,csvData.length, 
 csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);


 }
```

Comment: If you saying that you are trying to use an onEdit trigger when the Google Form writes to the linked sheet, then you should know that onEdit triggers only fire on user edits.

Comment: I can't tell that code has anything to do with onFormSubmit or onedit .  It seems to be code for extracting csv files from email attachments.

Comment: @Cooper I was using a separate on edit script but it was working. I was hoping I could add something to this script to add the info.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  I need more information.

Comment: @Cooper Do you know of a way to have a time time generate on the results with this script is ran?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function importCSVFromGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.search("Gmail Search");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages();
  var attachment = message[message.length - 1].getAttachments()[1];
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET ID');
  var tab = sheet.getSheetByName('Data');
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");
  let o = csvData.map(r => {
    let x = r.slice();
    x.push(new Date());
    return x;
  }})
  var startRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  tab.getRange(startRow, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```